# JSON fields name for POJO class

Tags: java, json, rest, mapping

I have a simple Java class:

```
class Feed { 
private String fieldOne;
private String fieldTwo;
}
```

and a JSON connected with this class:

```
{
  "feed": {
    "field_one": "1.780",
    "field_two": "1.810"
}
```

but when I send this json to server, all class fields are null. If i change fields name in JSON to `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo` it works fine. But is it possible to read this json without doing any changes in fields name in JSON or class?

Comment: Depending on your underlying JSON provider, you should be able to annotate your class to say what the expected field names are.

Comment: So I need to use @JsonProperty annotation and this is a solution?

Comment: In addition to rmlan's comment: some libraries such as Jackson support the use of mixins, i.e. you don't have to change the `Feed` pojo to "add" the annotations (if you really need to keep `Feed` as it is). Others make use of some sort of configuration, e.g. via some file.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this :

```
class Feed { 
@XmlElement(name="field_one")
private String fieldOne;

@XmlElement(name="field_two")
private String fieldTwo;
}
```

Comment: It is JSON, not a XML. I think I need to use @JsonProperty

Comment: We use @XmlElemen also for Json try it.